# How to add Hebrew vowels in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, hebrew

With older versions of windows I would do [this](http://www.qsm.co.il/Hebrew/wniqud.htm) but that doesn't work anymore with Word 2010.

Comment: Looks like there's some good info to [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/hebrew-fonts-in-word-2010-do-not-show-as-hebrew/95fb38d6-03f8-41e3-a4d7-91dcd2847433) Microsoft Community question, especially this Office Support article on [_About creating a Hebrew document_](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/about-creating-a-hebrew-document-HP003089536.aspx).

Comment: I didn't see anything there about vowels (nekudot) though. I know they're supported in later versions of word because when I open up old files from previous versions they display fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't caused by Word 2010, but by Windows 8.

Windows 8 added a new keyboard layout, Hebrew (Standard), in which this functionality does not work.

To restore this functionality, change your keyboard layout to Hebrew, and remove the Hebrew (Standard) layout.

More information can be found at: [Typing Hebrew Niqqud (Voweling Points) in Windows 8](http://www.petri.co.il/typing-hebrew-vowels-niqqud-windows-8.htm)

Comment: I tried this on Windows 10 (1803) and the removal of the Hebrew (Standard) keyboard layout didn't take effect until I signed out and signed back in again. Until then, both keyboard layouts are still available, and it's not just enough to change the language to Hebrew, the appropriate keyboard layout also has to be selected (by default, using `Windows+SPACE`.